# how to check if an account has more than 100 cases

Tags: soql, case, account

I'd like to run a query to retrieve if an account has got more than 100 cases in it . I tried but nothing worked. Please anybody help me out.

I tried this :

> select name from account where id in (select accountid from case)

Comment: For what purpose do you need a query? Getting that information from reports is much better and faster.

Comment: I want to run a batch apex if the cases count is more than 100 . For that i need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this. use HAVING  clause with aggregate query with group by AccountId

```
SELECT count(Id) , AccountId FROM Case GROUP BY AccountId HAVING count(Id) > 100
```

you will get all the accountId where more than 100 cases are there.